# recordset method to replace dlookup (lazy) 'habit'?

Tags: ms-access

please pardon my virgin post and if my question somehow got answered elsewhere, please kindly point me to that link (i did read related dlookup topic but didnt get what i want).

i freq use dlookup (due to newbie in access and lazy too) on forms for my textbox to hold values for my purpose (calculations, display) and knowing dlookup is random and takes time if db isnt local (which i am task to move it online) and time for me to utilize more professional approach to replace dlookup usage in general.

what i used to do is to retrieve data from 1 table (inventory) to populate textbox in a form:

```
txtItemName=dlookup ("ItemName","Inventory","Inv_ID=" & cboItem)
txtItemDesc=dlookup ("ItemDesc","Inventory","Inv_ID=" & cboItem)
txtItemPrice=dlookup ("ItemPrice","Inventory","Inv_ID=" & cboItem)
```

and such for data i need and sometimes could be more 10 dlookup(s) to lookup data for my textboxes.

i did read about recordset (DAO/ADO) but due to newbie in ms-access usage, i couldnt figure how to write (or copy) code that could perform what i need like the above dlookup(s).

i did try creating query to pull fields (say 10 fields) i need in 1 query and use dlookup (again) in recordsource to hold the value. (if this method has any advantage compared to 10x original dlookup i did before...)

i am willing to learn the right method to do the right thing in ms-access and seek all seniors to show me the way and kick my bad/newbie habit of abusing dlookup.

i thank you all in advance.

Comment: today is my lucky day! while continue to search for the answer, i came across other post that gave a simple code :
-----------
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "Select * From db_Inventory Where Item_Rec = " & Me!Combo12
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Me!txtItemCode = rst!Item_Code
    Me!txtItemDesc = rst!Item_Desc
    Me!txtItemPrice = rst!Retail_Price
    Me!txtPriceGroup = rst!Retail_Price_Grp
End If
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
----------
the above works after some editing :) and hope this would help someone

Comment: see my comments below - using a recordset in code will not run faster. So the advice to not use dlookup() is wrong, and you are free to use it. The issue is if you using the dlookup() over and over - that's when it is slow, but so will that VBA function when you use it over and over also!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using dlookup() or using VBA code and a reocrdset?

The performance is 100% the SAME.

I repeat the performance is 100% the SAME.

You gain ZERO benefits by writing some VBA code that creates a recordset, and then creates the sql, and then pulls the one record. It is in fact a waste of time to pursue such a road and concept. It does NOT HELP performance at all, and using VBA code + a reocrdset to pull the one record and value is NOT faster.

They both perform the SAME speed!!!

What can make a difference? If you have dlookup() over and over in the sql, and you execute dlooup() for EACH ROW of the sql. Then that is slow.

So, say we had a combo box, and we have say the "id, HotelName".

So, in a query you might do this:

```
 select FirstName, LastName, dlookup("HotelName","tblHotels","ID = " & Hotel_ID) from bookings
```

In above, we used dlookup() to get the Hotel name, since I did not want to display the "hotel_id". Above is going to be VERY slow. The faster way is to use a sql join like this:

```
 SELECT FistName, LastName, Hotel_id, tblHotels.HotelName
 LEFT JOIN tblHotels on tblBookings.Hotel_id = tblHotels.id
 FROM tblBookings.
```

So, in above, we dumped the dlookup() (slow), to above, which will run very fast.

So, running ONE dlookup() vs VBA + reocrdset to get the ONE value? Same speed, no need to use VBA code to replace the dlookup() function.

But, if you run the function over and over - one time for each row? Then BOTH use of dlookup(), and use of a custom VBA function to do that for each row will BOTH be slow.

Comment: wow... after reading many post on dlookup, your answer definitely is new way of looking at it. The main reason i seek to resolve 'performance' issue is due to everytime a user select an item from a combo box, dlookup some info to display (for user) and info to calculate the price, and then store them into the table. i will read again and again on your reply when i goes to office later. thanks for the new insight.

Comment: Remember, the compare has a limited context. If you just grabbing ONE value? Then dlookup() is just as fast as the whole VBA + reocrdset to get that one value. The huge difference is that with a reocrdset, you can get MORE then one value, and many rows of data in one shot  - and in that case, the recordset is MUCH faster. However, a direct 1 to 1 replacement of dlookup() with VBA + recordset is NOT faster. So the real issue is the "context" here. Dlookup() is not slow to get one value, but if you grabbing many values with many dlookups(), then yes it is slow due to using it many times!!!